# Magento 2 Ui component model not opening | Related Products

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento2.3.0, related-products

I'm trying to implement the same functionality as we get in Product edit form for Add new Related Products.

In my custom module, I've tried to implement the same functionality.

So I've I'm getting the Button "Add Related Products" but clicking on it not opening the model.

I'm not able to track the issue, Can anyone help me? 
Let me know if you want more code/files details.

Following is code for that

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductLinkInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductLinkRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeSetRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;

class VirtualDataProvider extends AbstractModifier
{
    const DATA_SCOPE = '';
    const DATA_SCOPE_RELATED = 'related';
    const DATA_SCOPE_UPSELL = 'upsell';
    const DATA_SCOPE_CROSSSELL = 'crosssell';
    const GROUP_RELATED = 'related';

    private static $previousGroup = 'search-engine-optimization';
    private static $sortOrder = 90;
    protected $locator;
    protected $urlBuilder;
    protected $productLinkRepository;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $imageHelper;
    protected $status;
    protected $attributeSetRepository;
    protected $scopeName;
    protected $scopePrefix;
    private $priceModifier;
    private $layoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ProductLinkRepositoryInterface $productLinkRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        Status $status,
        AttributeSetRepositoryInterface $attributeSetRepository,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        $scopeName = '',
        $scopePrefix = ''
    )
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->productLinkRepository = $productLinkRepository;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->attributeSetRepository = $attributeSetRepository;
        $this->scopeName = $scopeName;
        $this->scopePrefix = $scopePrefix;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
    }


    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $content = __(
            'Add new products'
        );
        $this->scopePrefix = '';

        $meta['new_test_fieldset'] = [
            'children' => [
                "test_name" => $this->getTextFieldConfig(10, 'test_name', 'test Name'),
                "add_product" => $this->getStepsFieldset()
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $meta;
    }
    protected function getTextFieldConfig($sortOrder, $name, $label)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __($label),
                        'formElement' => Field::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => $name,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        "required" => 1,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    protected function getStepsFieldset(){
        $content = __(
            'Related products are shown to customers in addition to the item the customer is looking at.'
        );

        return [
            'children' => [
                'button_set' => $this->getButtonSet(
                    $content,
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED
                ),
                'modal' => $this->getGenericModal(
                    __('Add Related Products'),
                    static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED
                ),
                static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED => $this->getGrid(static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED),
            ],
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__fieldset-section',
                        'label' => __('Related Products'),
                        'collapsible' => false,
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    protected function getButtonSet(Phrase $content, Phrase $buttonTitle, $scope)
    {
        $modalTarget = static::GROUP_RELATED . '.' . $scope . '.modal';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'formElement' => 'container',
                        'componentType' => 'container',
                        'label' => false,
                        'content' => $content,
                        'template' => 'ui/form/components/complex',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'button_' . $scope => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'formElement' => 'container',
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
                                'actions' => [
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget,
                                        'actionName' => 'toggleModal',
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        'targetName' => $modalTarget . '.' . $scope . '_product_listing',
                                        'actionName' => 'render',
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'title' => $buttonTitle,
                                'provider' => null,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
    protected function getGrid($scope)
    {
        $dataProvider = $scope . '_product_listing';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'label' => null,
                        'columnsHeader' => false,
                        'columnsHeaderAfterRender' => true,
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'template' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/templates/grid',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                        'addButton' => false,
                        'recordTemplate' => 'record',
                        'dataScope' => 'data.links',
                        'deleteButtonLabel' => __('Remove'),
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'map' => [
                            'id' => 'entity_id',
                            'name' => 'name',
                            'status' => 'status_text',
                            'attribute_set' => 'attribute_set_text',
                            'sku' => 'sku',
                            'price' => 'price',
                            'thumbnail' => 'thumbnail_src',
                        ],
                        'links' => [
                            'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                        ],
                        'sortOrder' => 2,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => 'container',
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'dataScope' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => $this->fillMeta(),
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function fillMeta()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->getTextColumn('id', false, __('ID'), 0),
            'thumbnail' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/thumbnail',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'thumbnail',
                            'fit' => true,
                            'label' => __('Thumbnail'),
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'name' => $this->getTextColumn('name', false, __('Name'), 20),
            'status' => $this->getTextColumn('status', true, __('Status'), 30),
            'attribute_set' => $this->getTextColumn('attribute_set', false, __('Attribute Set'), 40),
            'sku' => $this->getTextColumn('sku', true, __('SKU'), 50),
            'price' => $this->getTextColumn('price', true, __('Price'), 60),
            'actionDelete' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'additionalClasses' => 'data-grid-actions-cell',
                            'componentType' => 'actionDelete',
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'label' => __('Actions'),
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'fit' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'position' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => 'position',
                            'sortOrder' => 80,
                            'visible' => false,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getTextColumn($dataScope, $fit, Phrase $label, $sortOrder)
    {
        $column = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text',
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => $dataScope,
                        'fit' => $fit,
                        'label' => $label,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $column;
    }

    protected function getGenericModal(Phrase $title, $scope)
    {
        $listingTarget = $scope . '_product_listing';

        $modal = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Modal::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'options' => [
                            'title' => $title,
                            'buttons' => [
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Cancel'),
                                    'actions' => [
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [
                                    'text' => __('Add Selected Products'),
                                    'class' => 'action-primary',
                                    'actions' => [
                                        [
                                            'targetName' => 'index = ' . $listingTarget,
                                            'actionName' => 'save'
                                        ],
                                        'closeModal'
                                    ]
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                $listingTarget => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'autoRender' => false,
                                'componentType' => 'insertListing',
                                'dataScope' => $listingTarget,
                                'externalProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '_data_source',
                                'selectionsProvider' => $listingTarget . '.' . $listingTarget . '.product_columns.ids',
                                'ns' => $listingTarget,
                                'render_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('mui/index/render'),
                                'realTimeLink' => true,
                                'dataLinks' => [
                                    'imports' => false,
                                    'exports' => true
                                ],
                                'behaviourType' => 'simple',
                                'externalFilterMode' => true,
                                'imports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.provider }:data.product.current_store_id',
                                ],
                                'exports' => [
                                    'productId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_product_id',
                                    'storeId' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.current_store_id',
                                ]
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $modal;
    }
}
```

[image]

Above is image for that, Model should open on click of button but nothing is happning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've resolved by myself, Button action was wrong.